# Angular $scope variable doesn't change immediately when use promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I've been making UI by using md-switch.

What I want is

A). When user click md-switch, update some data.

B). If updating is failed, md-switch must go back to former status.

But in the B situation, md-switch doesn't work.

Weird thing is when I click other area (button or something), md-switch go back only then.
(exactly, $scope.privacyData is changed only then)

any advice?

here my codes.  thank you.

html:

```
<md-switch ng-show="myVideo" ng-model="privacyData"
ng-change="changePrivacyStatus()" aria-label="Switch 1">
</md-switch>
```

controller:

```
function changePrivacyStatus() {
  // $http.put('/api/lectures', privacyData)
  Promise.reject(new Error('fail'))
  .then(() => {
    console.log('DONE.');
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    $scope.privacyData = !$scope.privacyData;
    console.error(e);
  });
}
```

Comment: have you tried using $timeout?

Comment: you should rather use angular's `$q`

Comment: I think this is a use case for `$apply`, if you must use native promises that is. The `.catch` will be happening outside of angulars knowing. So its bindings are not updated. The `$q` service provides promises but it also does more then that. It means when its promises are resolved or rejected it also updates its associated bindings. Which the native does not.